# Timing of execution of AsyncTask onCancelled() and AsyncTask.doInBackground()

Tags: android

According to the Android Reference for the [AsyncTask.cancel method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29), the timing between onCancelled() and doInBackground() is explicitly defined:

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked

However, looking at my logcat I can see that the onCancelled() method is executed before the doInBackground() method returns.

```
07-10 12:38:57.000: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): doInBackground entered
07-10 12:38:57.000: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): AsyncTask attempting to take the lock
07-10 12:38:57.000: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): AsyncTask got the lock
07-10 12:38:57.420: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): Start Item[0].state = 0
07-10 12:38:57.933: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): onProgressUpdate entered
07-10 12:38:57.940: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): onProgressUpdate exited
07-10 12:38:58.320: VERBOSE/(7473): onCancelListener cancelling AsyncTask
07-10 12:38:58.400: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): onCancelled entered
07-10 12:38:58.400: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): onCancelled exited
07-10 12:38:58.560: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): Started checking file URL
07-10 12:38:58.601: VERBOSE/FileHost(7473): checkFile entered
07-10 12:38:58.641: VERBOSE/FileHost(7473): checkFile checking URI
07-10 12:38:58.691: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7473): threadid=19 wakeup: interrupted
07-10 12:38:58.710: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): AsyncTask released the lock
07-10 12:38:58.710: VERBOSE/AsyncTask(7473): doInBackground exited
```

Using the debugger and setting breakpoints at the onCancelled() method and the end of the doInBackground() method, I can also see that onCancelled() is called before the end of the doInBackground().

Is there some way that I have mis-coded something in my AsyncTask to bring about this difference in behaviour between the Android Reference and my application behaviour?

Edited to add some code for Gallal:

@Gallal, the Activity contains this piece of code.

```
private class OnCancelListener implements AddUrlDialog.CancelListener {
  @Override
  public void cancel() {
    if (addUrlInProgress == true) {
      addUrlInProgress = false;
      Log.v(TAG, "onCancelListener cancelling AsyncTask");
      addUrlControl.stopUpdates(true);
      AddUrlDialog.dismiss();
    }
  } 
}
```

The AsyncTask.cancel is called in the addUrlControl.stopUpdates() method.

```
public void stopUpdates(boolean cleanupLists) {
  if (asyncTaskExited != true) {
      cancelRequest = true; 
        addUrlAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        //TEST httpRequest.abort(); // Also sends an abort to the HTTP request
  }
}
```

The AsyncTask doInBackground method looks likes this.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
  Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground entered");

    netConn = addUrlControl.myApp.getNetConn();
    client = netConn.getHttpClient();

    try {
      doInBackgroundBody();
  } catch (Throwable t) {
      Log.e(TAG, "doInBackgroundBody threw an exception: ", t);
  } finally {
      addUrlControl.myApp.releaseNetConn();
  }

    Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground exited");        
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the order of the log messages always the same? You are logging from different threads so the order of the messages in logcat can change between application runs and appear wrong.

Comment: @Herrrmann, the order of log messages is the same. Putting breakpoints in the debugger show that onCancelled() is called before the end of doInBackground() returns.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm (as some of you already stated) that there is a [bug in the Android source for 2.x versions](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19029) that makes `onCancelled()` be called just after `cancel()` and before `doInBackground()` finishes.

So, if you were doing the clean up in `onCancelled()` you will actually do this at the same time as the AsyncTask is running and this will crash your app! This makes us change the design...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
addUrlAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

return?

If the Task cannot be interrupted it will run until it is finished.

Do you have a loop inside doInBackgroundBody()? I.e. the following implementation of doInBackground() would catch the InterruptedException that is thrown when calling myTask.cancel(true) and thus the loop will go on until the loop condition does evaluate to false.

```
        int count = 0;
        while(count++ < 10){
            try {
                Log.d("MyAsyncTask", "WORKING doInBackground() is cancelled: " + this.isCancelled());
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //break or return missing here to end the loop
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Hermann, the cancel() methods returns true:

    07-10 16:24:03.743: VERBOSE/stopUpdates(4568): addUrlAsyncTask.cancel(true) returned true


Yes, I have a loop inside the doInBackground() method. I also call isCancelled() to check for cancellation. The isCancelled() method returns true.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to a bug that I haven't been able to find a whole lot of information about. Except that I'm having the same problem. According to this discussion: [AsyncTask's cancel method - possible bug](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/07ea01892ee7a5f4/9f71428217c2cd44?pli=1) it's a race in the cancel() code that should be fixed in post froyo builds.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up. I'll have a play with a post froyo build and see what happens.

Comment: Damn, it still seems to happening on 2.3 for me.

Comment: Are you using the interrupt exception to cancel your doInbackground function? If not: What I ended up doing was setting a variable in the AsyncTask class, and check that inside my doInbackground processing loop. Then in postExecute I can distinguish between a cancelled task or one that completed by checking that variable.

Comment: In addition to calling AsyncTask.abort() I also cancel any ongoing HTTP request (which will cause an exception). I also check isCancelled() in the AsyncTask and isCancelled() returns true in the case that cancellation has happened, so I in fact know if the AsyncTask has been cancelled. It's just that the timing of the invocation of the onCancelled() method was not what I expected. Not to worry, I'll simply not bother with onCancelled(). I seem to be spending an inordinate amount of time on this, and I think I'll just change my design. Thanks everyone!