# what is the exact use of onCancelled(Object result) method in AsyncTask android?

Tags: android

when calling

```
cancel(true);
```

on asyncTaskObj bring user to

```
onCancelled()
```

method. when and why

```
onCancelled(Object result)
```

will be called and what is the use of it?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641322/timing-of-execution-of-asynctask-oncancelled-and-asynctask-doinbackground?rq=1)

Comment: The Official document exists for this kinds of concern. [AsnycTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object),

instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns.

it is from Android Developer documentation developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You may check isCancelled() to finish the working of doInbackground if it has loop

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... obj) {
  while (/* condition */) {

//.......

    if (isCancelled()) break;
  }
  return myReturn;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, but you should reference the source, which is obviously the official api documentation.

Comment: Thanks JHH for your advice. it is from Android Developer documentation
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

- A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking **cancel(boolean)**.
- Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to **isCancelled()** to
  return true.
- After invoking this method, **onCancelled(Object)**, instead of
  onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[])
  returns.
- To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should
  always check the return value of **isCancelled()** periodically from
  doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

[description for cancel() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

[description for isCancelled() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29)

[description for onCancelled() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled(Result))...

> Runs on the UI thread after cancel(boolean) is invoked and doInBackground(Object[]) has finished.
>
> The default implementation simply invokes onCancelled() and ignores the result. If you write your own implementation, do not call super.onCancelled(result).

Obviously, it gives you the chance to react after the operation has finally been cancelled such as changing the state of some UI components or notifying the user. For example, say you are executing a long running operation such as downloading a file, while the file is downloading you display a progress bar, but you also expose a "cancel" button so that the user can cancel the download.

Once cancel is clicked you can stop the progress bar and display a "Cancelling..." text when "onCancelled" is triggered you can hide the "cancel" button, the status text view and the progress bar.